# Cannot telnet from docker container in elastic beanstalk to different ec2 on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group

I'm trying to telnet from a docker instance on Elastic Beanstalk to a different EC2 instance within the same VPC. I've created a security group allowing inbound traffic from the Elastic Beanstalk security group id to the other EC2 instance.

after ssh'ing into one of the Elastic Beanstalk instances, I can confirm that I am able to telnet from Elastic Beanstalk instance to the other EC2 instance.

Successful:

```
[root@ip-111-11-11-111 ~]#  telnet 222.22.22.22 9999
Trying 222.22.22.22...
Connected to 222.22.22.22.
Escape character is '^]'
```

But, when I connect to the docker container interactively (via docker run -it) and try to run the same command above, no connection is made:

failure:

```
[root@ip-111-11-11-111 ~]# sudo su -
[root@ip-111-11-11-111 ~]#  docker exec -it my_instance /bin/sh
/path-of-user # telnet 222.22.22.22 9999
(hangs here, never connects)
```

So clearly the security group works for the Elastic Beanstalk instance but not the docker instance inside of the Elastic Beanstalk instance. I'm not sure what the correct changes to the security group would be to allow traffic from the docker instance inside of the Elastic Beanstalk instance to the different EC2 instance. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you allowing ec2 private ip or public ip only ?. Can you ping on that ip instead of telnet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The telnet command inside the docker container ended up being a false positive of the connection to the external ip not working. After further debugging the issue, the connection was actually being made, but apparently the Alpine distro that I was running in docker simple *does not* output anything even though it was indeed connecting. I was able to confirm the connection when I noticed messages successfully passing through my external Kafka setup.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd check docker's configuration, e.g., if you do `sudo docker ps` can you see that your docker have ports forwarding configured correctly? You should have something like `0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp`.